# Why does the BB84 paper "Quantum cryptography: Public key distribution and coin tossing" have a 'withdrawn' status?

Tags: soft-question, quantum-information, specific-reference, history

The original paper proposing quantum key distribution protocol (now known as [BB84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB84)):

- Charles H. Bennett, Gilles Brassard, [Quantum cryptography: Public key distribution and coin tossing](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2011.08.039)

seems to have `WITHDRAWN` status with a note:

> This article has been withdrawn at the request of the author(s) and/or editor. The Publisher apologizes for any inconvenience this may cause. The full Elsevier Policy on Article Withdrawal can be found at http://www.elsevier.com/locate/withdrawalpolicy.

Is it known why the paper was withdrawn, and is there any way to still access the paper?

Is it known if it is the same paper (the date is 28 September 2011 rather than anything in 1984)?

Comment: One of the reason's for withdrawal in press is "accidental duplicate" which may explain the date issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about publication dates rather than physics

Comment: The real question is: why was this article reprinted by *Theoretical Computer Science* 27 years after the original publication date, apparently without the publisher having obtained adequate copyright permissions?

Comment: @PeterShor I saw a few times an article being republished (I have no idea about its practical or legal side; especially I don't track which small journal/conference is owned by another). For an example, see this reprint of the original Shannon paper: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=584093.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the reprint was withdrawn, rather than the original article; probably, for copyright reasons.

Comment: Piotr's link is to the DOI page and the withdraw policy link is to the publisher's policy.

Comment: @dmckee: Maybe I don't quite understand your comment... The DOI points to a 2011 article, whereas the original article is dated 1984 (http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~chong/290N-W06/BB84.pdf ) I don't think the authors published an article with the same title 30 years later. That is why I suspect a reprint was withdrawn, rather than the original article..